# Count The number of Visit in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to find out a way to record the number of the visit of a person in my table, so that if it is the first time then I need to have the number in the Visits equal to 1 and in the second time this person come the number in the visit should be 2.

Below is a description to the situation.

```
CNT   PATID     DATE      PATName  VISIT
----------------------------------------
300   3001   16/08/2015    Jason     1
300   3002   16/08/2015    Sayde     1
300   3003   20/08/2015    Sayde     2
300   3004   20/08/2015    wetni     1
300   3005   20/08/2015    Jason     2
```

The column Visit is the thing I want to be able to calculate and show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to calculate this on  the fly with row_number() function

```
select CNT,   PATID,     DATE,      PATName, 
row_number() over (partition by PATName order by PATID) as VISIT
from table
```

The above will work in SQL Server and ORACLE. If you use MySQL, you need to use a variable

Comment: There are many more DBMS that support window functions. Not just Oracle and SQL Server. The query will work in Postgres, DB2, SAP Hana, Ingres, Informix, Teradata, Vertica and probably some more